# Knowing whether or not FTP is still connected with ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I was wondering if there is an easy way of knowing whether a connection to an FTP server is still active using ftplib.

So if you have an active connection like this:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.myserver.com", "admin", "pass123")
```

is there something like the following pseudo code that can be queried to check if the connection is still active?

```
if ftp.is_connected() == True:
    print "Connection still active"
else:
    print "Disconnected"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try retrieving something from the server, and catching any exceptions and returning whether or not it's connected based on that.

For example:

```
def is_connected(ftp_conn):
    try:
        ftp_conn.retrlines('LIST')
    except (socket.timeout, OSError):
        return False
    return True
```

This simple example will print the 'LIST' results to stdout, you can change that by putting your own callback into the [retrlines method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines)

---

(Make sure you set a timeout in the initial FTP object construction, as the default is for it to be None.)

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.gnu.org", timeout=5, user='anonymous', passwd='')
```

Comment: Oh right, that's actually a pretty simple way of doing it. Thanks.